# What does mean "I want some of what you're having" here?

Tags: meaning

"And if that's not the most hardcore thing you've ever heard, then I want some of what you're having."

I know what two sentences mean. But l can't understand what the relationship between two sentences is.

So could please explain it to me?

The fuller text is here:

And thus, his hope would also be his undoing. The Communists captured
Pilecki in 1947, and they didn’t go easy on him. He was tortured for almost a
year, so harshly and consistently that he told his wife that “Auschwitz was
just a trifle” by comparison.
Still, he never cooperated with his interrogators.
Eventually, realizing they could get no information from him, the
Communists decided to make an example of him. In 1948, they held a show
trial and charged Pilecki with everything from falsifying documents and
violating curfew to engaging in espionage and treason. A month later, he was
found guilty and sentenced to death. On the final day of the trial, Pilecki was
allowed to speak. He stated that his allegiance had always been to Poland and
its people, that he had never harmed or betrayed any Polish citizen, and that
he regretted nothing. He concluded his statement with “I have tried to live my
life such that in the hour of my death I would feel joy rather than fear.”
And if that’s not the most hardcore thing you’ve ever heard, then I want
some of what you’re having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an informal, and roundabout way of the author simply asserting that he believes the situation he has described is hardcore. (The precise meaning of “hardcore” is not relevant.)

It works by the author essentially asking the reader to agree with him (that it is hardcore). And he makes it clear that he is so sure the reader *will* agree with him, that in the unlikely event that the reader doesn’t, then the only plausible explanation is that the reader has consumed some mind altering substance that has made them temporarily unable to think rationally, and since such mind alterations are typically reported to be pleasurable (i.e. getting high or drunk) the author would like to share in that pleasurable experience.

That’s why common variants of “some of what you’re having” are “whatever you’re smoking”, or “whatever you’ve been drinking”